# Ajax "stack" variable into text file instead of posting it twice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

So I am posting a variable to a .txt file the variable is 10
each time I post the variable the .txt simply keeps adding "10" instead of stacking it so on the first post it should be 10 and then on the second post it should be 20  and then on the 3rd it should be 30 how do I go about this? .txt file is blank here's my code so far:

PHP:

```
<?php 
$Winner = $_POST['Winner'] ? $_POST['Winner'] : 'not set';
$file = fopen('file.txt','a+');
fwrite($file, $Winner.PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart tap', '#submit', function() {

var Winner = 10;
 $.ajax({
    url:'rate.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{Winner:Winner},
    success:function(data){
       alert('Data Stored');
    } 
});
   
});
```

Comment: In your PHP, you have `$file = fopen('file.txt','a+');`, this sets the file to Append. So a new line will be written with `$Winner` variable. Do you want a new line with the new value or just a single line with the new value (the old value overwritten)?

Comment: @Twisty I would like to know how to do both just incase I need one in the future if it's not to much trouble :) but a single line will do for what I have

Comment: In the future, I would strongly advise using an SQL Database, CSV, or Session Variable for storage versus a text file. One answer has already been posted.

Comment: @Twisty this is just for a simple like button :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file into a variable. Add the parameter to this, then write out the new value.

```
$score = intval(file_get_contents("file.txt"));
$score += intval($_POST['Winner']);
file_put_contents("file.txt", $score . PHP_EOL);
```